# Import and parse XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, import, simplexml

I am trying to import a XML file via API into my php script which then will parse said XML file and extract a string. Ive searched across the webspace for an answer, and though I have found a ton of resources I still cannot get this script to work.

The XML file that I am loading will look something like this

```
<api version="2">
  <currentTime>2012-07-28</currentTime>
    <result>
      <rowset name="accounts" key="accountID" columns="accountID,accountKey,balance">
        <row accountID="555555555" accountKey="6666" balance="7777777777.23"/>
      </rowset>
    </result>
  <cachedUntil>2012-07-28</cachedUntil>
</api>
```

I am trying to get my php script to fetch the value of the attribute **balance**.
This is the code that I have put together so far:

```
<?php

$apiurl = "api.some-arbitrary-api-site.com;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($apiurl);

print_r($xml);
$balance = $xml->balance;
print_r($balance);    

?>
```

This returns:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

Also following some other web tutorials I have tried this change

```
$balance = $xml->row->attributes()->balance;
print_r($balance);
```

Which spits out

```
Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in C:\xampp\htdocs\EVE\progress\import.php on line 22

Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in C:\xampp\htdocs\EVE\progress\import.php on line 22
```

What am I doing wrong? The end result is for the page to load this API and fetch the balance once every two days and store the data to be used in a chart rendered using highchart.

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I don't know simplexml but shouldn't it be `$xml->result->rowset->row->attributes()->balance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Musa answered the question

> I don't know simplexml but shouldn't it be
>   $xml->result->rowset->row->attributes()->balance – Musa

I was being an idiot and didnt check the xml over again when typing in the path.

Thanks